# How to setImageResource from List< > = new ArrayList<>()

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-imageview

I have a GridViewActivity, GridViewAdapter, FullScreenActivity and FullScreenImageAdapter. When I click Image from GridView, go to FullScreenActivity and it doesn't show nothing. I also test from Drawable `imgDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);` It doesn't happen. What wrong? How can I solve? Please!

In GridViewAdapter; Image Click Listener,

```
private class OnImageClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    int _postion;

    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this._postion = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("position", _postion);
        _activity.startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

In FullScreenActivity; get position from GridView, and then I create new FullScreenImageAdapter

```
List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
Log.i("Result", String.valueOf(position)); // return 0,1,2,3.. etc
adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenActivity.this, mItems);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In FullScreenImageAdapter;

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity _activity;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> mItems) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this.mItems = mItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imgDisplay;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container, false);
        imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        imgDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.a); // want to show from mItems List
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);
        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to put debug point at your FullScreenImageAdapter's instantiateItem() method and check if it is calling.

Comment: How to do that ? Sir

Comment: You should learn this concepts before starting actual coding. Take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html . For now the small bar to the left of your code (where you see line numbers), click there and you can see a red dot, which means your code will stop there in debug mode and you can analyse all your values. To run in debug more press button to right of run or press Shift + F9.

Comment: Seems your `mItems` is `empty`. You'r only passing `position` and in code i can't see at where you'r using it.

Comment: You should send selected Item Object rather sending position only.